# Открытие activity в отдельном окне

Tags: java, android

Как сделать что бы новая activity открывалась не по верх другой, а как бы в новом окне, т.е чтобы при нажатии на кнопку последних программ пользователь видел и новую активити и ее родителя? Например в приложении почта mail.ru когда нажимаешь на итем новое сообщение, ты можешь что то написать(но не отправлять), затем вернуться в основное приложение и что то сделать там, а потом снова продолжить писать текст сообщения, к тому же можно так делать много раз и в истории программ будет много этих активити с новыми сообщениями

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хоть я и не смотрел, что за приложение от mail, но скорее всего это не активити а фрагменты, а состояния они свое сохраняют в жизненном цикле

Comment: Добавил скриншот для наглядности, так можно сделать только используя фрагмент? И если да то как конкретно?

Comment: а если закрыть почту, то окно сообщения закроется?

Comment: я думаю это отдельное приложение, которое из первого приложения открывает через тип intent для отправки сообщение второе приложение.

Comment: Останется ( по крайней мере если "свайп или крестик" это закрыть в Android :) )

Comment: тогда мой последний комментарий выше

Comment: Я тоже об этом думал, но в меню смартфона и в списке приложений (в настройках) нет отдельной программы, да и когда устанавливаешь с плей маркета, там только одно приложение. Да и к тому же новое сообщение можно открыть много раз, и каждый раз оно откроется "в новом окне"

Comment: это не просто "окна", это отдельные таски. Советую почитать об launchMode для активностей. Там есть разные атрибуты, возможно один из них и поможет.

Comment: @TyDM, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents.html - по-моему этот гайд по Вашей теме.

Answer (score 5):

UPD: Может кому то будет полезно. Только api>21(android 5.0)

```
intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT); // что бы активити запустилась в новом окне
// если нужно что бы каждый раз активити была в новом окне, то еще и:
intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK); // каждый запуск в новом окне
```

Можно так же прописать для Activity эти параметры в манифесте, подробнее [developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents.html)